# How do I correctly set up an API key in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-cloud-platform, api-key

I am trying to deploy a project in GCP that needs OpenAI API key. I set the API key as an environment variable from the cloud shell terminal as follows:

```
export OPENAI_API_KEY='sh-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

And I can access it using Python as you can see here:

[image]

However, after I build a docker image of the project and try to run it, it gives the following error:

```
$ docker run app
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 684, in __setitem__
    value = self.encodevalue(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 756, in encode
    raise TypeError("str expected, not %s" % type(value).__name__)
TypeError: str expected, not NoneType
```

So, what's wrong here?

If I do the following, I don't get any error:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
>>>
```

So I don't understand why it is giving this error when running the docker image.

Answer (score 2):

Docker does not have access to the host environment variables. You need to pass them into the `docker run` call via [`-e|--env`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#env). Could you try:

```
docker run -e OPENAI_API_KEY='sh-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' app
```

or

```
docker run -e OPENAI_API_KEY="$OPENAI_API_KEY" app
```

Comment: Oh I see, got it